# JXTable and Header Cell Above Scrollbar

Tags: java, swing, jtable, swingx, jxtable

JTable and JXTables have a header cell that is generated above the scrollbar.  It's a small cell but I would like to use it to render an icon and popup menu.  How might I access this header cell?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In JXTable, the property to set is the columnControl: basically, it can be any component you like. To keep the functionality of the default, you can subclass ColumnControlButton